# Console app can't read registry keys which IIS app can read

Tags: c#, registry, console-application, owin

I am trying to read some registry keys in a console application (prior to setting up a self-hosted Owin application) so that I can acquire values which a Web API application uses under IIS. The console application is unable to see the same key entries which the Web API application can when running under IIS.

```
var c = Registry.LocalMachine
                .OpenSubKey(
                    @"SOFTWARE\APCI\AppServer",
                    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.ReadKey
                )
                .GetSubKeyNames();

Registry.LocalMachine.Close();
return c[0];
```

What should I change in the console app to let it read from the registry just as the Web API app does?

Comment: I supposed that you running console application using your user identity, most probably you encounter Registry Virtualization compatibility feature (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884(VS.85).aspx) and it transparently redirects you to HKEY_USERS entry instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which most probably used when you are running your API as IIS process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the Web API application was set to target the x86 platform in the project build tab. Setting it to x64 solved the problem.